# How can I bind sources of 3rd party jar to eclipse for debugging when jar is not on the class path

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar

I am using a 3rd party, open-source jar in my application. I develop the application in Eclipse. The jar is actually not on the classpath of the application, it is dynamically loaded by dependency injection framework (OSGI Felix here).

I have sources of the jar, but I do not want to build it.

How to to bind the sources to the jar in the Eclipse, so that I can put breakpoints and debug through code of this jar?

I think that differs if the jar is on the classpath, so I stress this fact.

Answer (score 0):

When you step into your method in Eclipse, if you don't have the source code of the jar you'll end up with this editor window:

[image]

Just click the `Attach Source..` button, and then select your jar that contains the source code. You'll be able to put break points and step inside the methods.

Comment: yes, this is a window which I would like to see. The trouble is that I do not actually know, where my (huge) code steps into the jar's code, so I wanted to use a breakpoint to find this out.

Comment: When you step into your huge jar, wherever you are in the jar, attach the whole jar with the source code and each class will be bound to it's java source code file.